# Is there a way to tell when fruit/trees are in season?

Tags: story-of-seasons

I've gotten myself an orchard going of all different sorts of fruits and nuts growing, but I'm having trouble remembering what grows when. Is there a way to tell when the tree is in or out of season so I don't waste fertilizer on trees that aren't producing?

Other than obviously "this tree is growing fruit, it's in season". I'm looking for more along the lines of how to tell what season the fruit is by the look of it's tree or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mature fruit trees that are in season, don't have fruit and haven't been harvested earlier in the day should have visible flowers:

[image: Peach tree with flowers]

Otherwise if you have any seedlings available for the tree you can tell what season they're for from the seedling's description. If you have a seed maker you can view a description of any seed or seedling (except the "mysterious seeds") by using the threshing machine, selecting the seed/seedling and pressing X.

[image: Muscat seedling decription]

         
[image: List of seeds and seedlings from the threshing machine]

As Yuuki says you can't waste fertilizer simply by applying it out of season. You can however apparently waste it by using it when the fruit is already at the 5 star level, and you can't really tell if you've reached that level unless you can harvest the fruit.

Comment: ah, I didn't think about looking in the seed maker. that works.

Comment: @Rapitor Yah, I didn't realize that until I went to dump a dried peach in the thresher so I could make a screenshot of a seedling's description.

Comment: Using fertilizer even when at 5 stars isn't actually a waste since storms/blizzards can knock off star rating. So continuing to fertilize adds a buffer. Of course, if you're growing everything in a greenhouse, then it is a waste.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of growth stages and simply knowing what trees are in season, you can't really tell whether a tree is in season. However, even if a tree isn't in season, fertilizer still increases the quality of the fruit produced, so it never really goes to waste.